# trying to delete files on WinSCP that have the owner Apache

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, winscp

WINSCP error: Permission denied. Error code: 3 Error message from server: Permission denied.

I created 11 folders with 1 picture in each of them while I was testing my website. I am now trying to delete those folders on WINSCP but I receive the error written above. The folders were created using a PHP script on my codeigniter application. The folders are created when a user is logged into the codeigniter application, and completes a form. 
I created the folder using the function: mkdir( $path ).
I copyed the image into the folder using the function: copy( $pic , $path).
On WinSCP the folders and pictures have the owner apache.

How can I delete the folders now? From what I understand I cannot delete the folders on WinSCP because I am logged into my personal account, not apache. I tried to make a link on my web application which changes permissions on a folder and login as the user account that created the folders. This returns me the codeignter error "chown: Operation not permitted".

So how can I delete the folders as the apache owner? Do I need to use the WinSCP console?

*I found out how to delete these folders. I made a delete component for my application. When the component was finished i logged in and used the delete component. This allowed me to delete the folders.*

Comment: Okay, so you are using your personal account, have you tried to login as root on winscp? If you are unable to do so, the root user needs to grant you permission to delete (ex chmod 777 yourusername -linux).

Answer (score 1):

Well as I understand, you are trying to delete folders while logged in with your personal account, but the folders are owned by apache user. There are several possible solutions for your problem.

One of them as suggested in the comment, is to login to WinSCP as root user.

Another option is to add your personal account to the apache group. If the folder that you want to delete is writable by group then you should be able to delete the folder

Another option is to run apache and php under your personal account.